# Статичный метод в локальном классе

Tags: java

Когда и где изменили возможности локального класса, в документации написано что он не может иметь статичных методов, но они прекрасно компилируются. Хочу найти в какой джаве это изменили.

Пример компилируемого кода

```
public void sayGoodbyeInEnglish() {
    class EnglishGoodbye {
        public static void sayGoodbye() {
            System.out.println("Bye bye");
        }
    }
    EnglishGoodbye.sayGoodbye();
}
```

Comment: Начиная с Java 16 можно

Comment: [Eng SO: Why are static methods allowed inside a non-static inner class in Java 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521280/)